# Programming with Dplyr - Passing a string to a function

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to pass a string to function that uses `dplyr::filter` but I'm not sure how to go about it even after reading [the article on the tidyverse website](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html). Grateful for any pointers.

Ideally I'm hoping to pass a string like 'survey' to the function below to have it used in the `str_detect` functions.

#### My attempt:

```
sel_measures <- function(data_source, variable) {
variable <- rlang::sym(variable)

data_source %>% 
 filter(str_detect(summary, !!variable) | 
           str_detect(labels, !!variable) | 
           str_detect(labels_1, !!variable) | 
           str_detect(labels_2, !!variable) | 
           str_detect(labels_3, !!variable) | 
           str_detect(labels, 'gene') | 
           str_detect(labels_1, 'gene') | 
           str_detect(labels_2, 'gene') | 
           str_detect(labels_3, 'gene') |
           str_detect(labels, 'nerv') | 
           str_detect(labels_1, 'nerv') | 
           str_detect(labels_2, 'nerv') | 
           str_detect(labels_3, 'nerv'),
           str_detect(issue_type, 'Task') |
           str_detect(issue_type, 'Issue')
         ) %>% select(summary, priority, assignee, 'last comment', labels) %>% 
  filter(status != 'Done') %>% 
  arrange(priority, status)
}
```

Comment: The fancy quoting/unquoting stuff is only needed when you are trying to pass the name of a column to a function. If you're passing a string in to the function, and it's being used as a string within a function, you don't need to quote it at all, you can remove the `rlang::sym()` call and all the `!!`.